# Printing utf-8 in windows cmd

Tags: python, utf-8, python-2.6

I am now building a battleships game in python and my printing function (the user can print his board) includes utf-8 character for the borders.

**The file:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function
import random
import numpy
import ascii_art
ROW_LEN = 10

def print_board(board):
    print (ascii_art.game_on + '\n', end="")
    for i in range(0, ROW_LEN - 1):
        print (' _______', end="")
    print(' _______ \n', end="")

    for x in range(0, ROW_LEN):
        for y in range(0, ROW_LEN):
            print ('│   ', end="")

            if board[x][y] != 'E':
                print (board[x][y], end="")
            else:
                print (' ', end="")
            print('   ', end="")

        print('│\n', end="")

        for j in range(0, ROW_LEN - 1):
            print(' ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯', end="")

        print(' ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯ \n', end="")
return 0

curr_board = construct_board() # constructs a board as a numpy array
player.print_board(curr_board.tolist())
```

However, every time I use

```
import codecs
codecs.register(lambda name: codecs.lookup('utf-8') if name == 'cp65001' else None)
```

I get gibberish on my cmd. How can I solve that?

Comment: You should encapsulate your strings into a Unicode object.

Comment: In the beginning of the file I added `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`, isn't that enough?

Comment: It would help us to answer your question if you could reduce your program to the shortest complete program that demonstrates the problem. Copy-paste that short program into your question.

Comment: Not on Python 2.6, it would be fine in Python 3. `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` guarantees that your characters will be encoded as utf-8, but not that they will be converted afterwards. Did you try something like `# -*- coding: cp65001 -*-`?

Comment: @Flav INow I get `encoding Problem: with BOM` (maybe that's because i'm using `import print from __future__`?) .

Comment: @Flav I don't think `cp65001` works until Python 3.3.

Comment: OK. Well I agree with @Robᵩ, we need a minimal example that we can directly run on our computers.